# my input type=file is not post by ajax or jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

i try to post data by ajax , it gives me `name` value bu not gives me `fileToUpload`

my code is

```
$.ajax({

  type: 'POST',

  url: 'image.php',

  data:{name :$('#name').val(), fileToUpload:$('#fileToUpload').val()  },
```

anybody help me please.

Comment: You cannot upload file with ajax like that. Try this plugin http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: hi, safarov thanks for reply, then how i can upload file by using jquiery only ?

Comment: Look at the plugin, it'll save you a lot of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here http://www.profilepicture.co.uk/ajax-file-upload-xmlhttprequest-level-2/ to learn more about ajax upload.

And an example for [JQuery plugin](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload)